# How to access a string from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

am getting following response from web service and i need to fetch the string

> Error: no record found in database.

shown below:

```
d =     (
    "Error: no record found in database."
);
```

here is my code

```
 if([[[[dictiona objectForKey:@"d"] objectForKey:@""] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"No Record Found"  delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];
}
```

Comment: where is your code? what is the dictionary? `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: what is the content-type of your web request? Is it JSON?

Comment: Try: `NSString *theString = [[dict objectForKey:@"MyArray"]objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: That is not a valid response ask your server guys to send xml response or json response

Comment: just ask him to send like this {"d":
    "Error: no record found in database."}

Comment: @Aditya Sinha yes it is json

Comment: @AmitSaini Try:
`NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];`

and see what you get!

Comment: @Aditya Sinha am getting following response   Dictonary = {
    d =     (
        "Error: no record found in database."
    );
}

Comment: @AmitSaini Awesome. then we are almost done. try `jsonDictionary[@"d"][0]`

Comment: @Aditya Sinha app crash -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: if([[[dictiona objectForKey:@"d"]  objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"No Record Found"  delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        
        [myAlertView show];
        
        dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
        
        return;
        
    }
    else if ([[[[dictiona objectForKey:@"d"] objectForKey:@"forum" ] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == YES)
    {
        dict=dictiona;
    }

Comment: @AmitSaini Ok. Can you let me know all the keys present in dictionary by executing `[jsonDictionary allKeys]`

Comment: i have two cases if or else in the if case Dictonary = {
    d =     (
        "Error: no record found in database."
    );in else part {"d":{"forum":[{"forumName":"General Clinical Engineering","country":"Norway","title":"Asf","details":"Google's latest doodle marks the 107th birth anniversary of American marine biologist, author and conservationist, blah blah blah

Comment: in if case i need to show alert because no record found and in else part in need to pass all the data to dictionary ,you can see code above comments..please help

Answer (score 1):

Your code should not check for a second objectForKey, as there isn't a second NSDictionary to check for, because your second item is an NSArray, which doesn't respond by keys. This should work for you instead:

```
if ([[[dictionary objectForKey:@"d"] objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"No Record Found"  delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [myAlertView show];
}
```

Comment: hello @troop231 i tried your code but app crash the following message is appear in console -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc0d9180

Comment: Please update your question to show the 2nd dictionary, as you only showed you key in the dictionary which is an array.